# RoR : routing design for project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, routes, symbols

I'm creating a new app on rails for two hotels. Ive managed to manipulate language by adding the following code

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es|fr/ do
   get 'hotels/main'
   get 'hotel1/home'
   get 'hotel1/gallery'
   ...
   get 'hotel2/home'
   get 'hotel2/gallery'
   ...
end
```

which gives in exchange the following routes:

```
(/:locale)/hotels/main(.:format)
(/:locale)/hotel1/home(.:format)
...
(/:locale)/hotel2/home(.:format)
...
```

What I would like to do is to have a variable called hotel_name with two options (hotel1, hotel2) and to call it in the routes.rb file so that instead of declaring all possibilities after the language I have the two choices (hotel1, hotel2) and the associated views (home, gallery, book, ...).

I tried creating a model hotel with the previous views but the two hotels would be like instances but I don't know if they should be persisted with active records since the only thing Im interested on is recognising which one is active, just like the language which I know is a symbol but in that case where should I declare it and how do I manipulate it?

Thanks

**Update 1**

Thanks @j-plato

I tried this and it worked:

```
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es|fr/ do
    scope "(:hotel_name)", name: /hotel1|hotel2/ do
      get 'home', controller: 'hotels', action: 'home'
      get 'gallery', controller: 'hotels', action: 'gallery'
      get 'book', controller: 'hotels', action: 'book'
      get 'tours', controller: 'hotels', action: 'tours'
      get 'directions', controller: 'hotels', action: 'directions'
      get 'visit', controller: 'hotels', action: 'visit'
    end
    get 'index', controller: 'hotels'
  end
```

however I could not pass the variable hotel_name because I have not instantiated the hotel. So where should I do it? although this is supposed to give this /locale/hotel_name/action it only shows locale/action because it cannot find the hotel_name

This works

```
<%= link_to "English", params.merge({:locale = 'en'}) %>
```

This doesn't

```
<%= link_to "hotel 1", params.merge({:hotel_name => 'hotel1'}), home_path %>
```

What do I need to do in order to have the possibility to switch between hotels and to pass the hotel_name parameter just like the :locale?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you probably want to route all these requests to the hotels controller, and have the hotel_name passed to the controller method as a parameter.  So what you can do is this:

```
get "hotels/:hotel_name/home", controller: "hotels", action: "home"
```

If you invoke it as:

```
http://my_hotel_app.com/fr/hotels/hotel1/home
```

The controller method "home" will be called with the parameter :hotel_name = "hotel1"